# How do I get a number from bytes?

Tags: lua, bytecode

I am currently trying to work around with Lua 5.1 bytecode. I've gotten pretty far, and understand a lot. However, I am stuck with a question on instructions and numbers. I understand that the size of the instruction and number are located and defined in the header, but I am not sure how to get the actual number from the 4 bytes (or whatever size is specified in the header).

I've looked at output from ChunkSpy and I don't really understand how it went from those bytes to the number. I'd look in the source but I don't want to just copy it, I want to understand it. If anyone could tell me a bit about it or even point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [A No-Frills Introduction to Lua 5.1 VM Instructions](http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf), numbers are stored in the constants pool.

The first byte is 3=LUA_TNUMBER.

The next bytes are the number, with the length as given in the header. Interpretation is based on the length, byte order and the integral flag as given in the header.

Typically, non-integral with 8 bytes means IEEE 754 64-bit double.

Deserializing bytes to double involves extracting the bits for the mantissa and exponent, and combining them with arithmetic operations. Perhaps you want that as a challenge and to start from a description of the standard: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), "Formats and Operations" section.

Comment: Yeah, that's the PDF I've been reading. Is this the same for the instructions as well? (extracting the bytes from it to get the instruction number)